# Changing my samba credential from Guest to "Samba_User"?

Tags: samba

I've looked and looked and couldn't find this question yet.
I have a PC with Ubuntu 20.04 sharing a folder via SAMBA.
On another PC I have a user who connects to that shared folder using the anonymous/guest access but I want to change that credential on the user PC to and already existing and operational SAMBA user.
Where can I change this on my User's PC?
Thanks

Comment: Hello. You change it on the server not the client. The user get prompted on attempt to access.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I don't want to change the password, as it's a general password shared by a few users. I don't want to go to each machine. The user has the anonymous/guest login memorized and doesn't have to type password everytime the folder is accessed. I just want to change the login type from guest to the one with the password for this specific person on this single machine...